# Get url from android browser

Tags: android, android-browser

is it possible to get callback whenever a url is opened from the android browser.

getallvisitedurls() method returns just url, I want it in realtime and with timestamp of the access.

Comment: I saw this http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-activity-and-browser-callback. I haven't tried it out myself though. Have a go.

Comment: yes its possible that how twitter api does to return aouth back

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The Android Browser does not emit a broadcast or anything like that whenever the user opens a URL in it. Besides, the user may be using a third party browser instead of the default one.

The only way you could do this is by making your own browser app and have the user use that one instead of the default browser that came with their ROM.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible to do so by using `retrieveRequestToken`.

The Twitter API returns a callback for OAuth, so I think it would be possible.

Have a look at [this post](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-activity-and-browser-callback). It explains how it is to be done and it sounds all good to me.

**Note :** I haven't tried it myself. So no guarantees. :)